Constructing a measure on R with certain representation
In constructing a measure on $\mathbb{R}$, my materials say:
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a collection of sets $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that admit the representation:
$
\begin{align}
& C = (a_1, b_1] \: \cup \: ... \: \cup \: (a_k, b_k] \\ \text{or} \\
& C = (-\infty, b_0] \: \cup \: (a_1, b_1] \: \cup \: ... \: \cup \: (a_k, b_k] \\ \text{or} \\
& C = (a_1, b_1] \: \cup \: ... \: \cup \: (a_k, b_k] \: \cup \: (a_{k+1}, \infty)
\\ \text{or} \\
& C = (-\infty, b_0] \: \cup \: (a_1, b_1] \: \cup \: ... \: \cup \: (a_k, b_k] \: \cup \: (a_{k+1}, \infty)
\end{align}
$
for $a_k < b_k$
We can check that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ = $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. I can see how $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}, \tau) = \sigma(\tau)$, because each $A \in \mathcal{A}$ has $A \in \sigma(\tau)$, so $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \sigma(\tau) \Rightarrow \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subseteq \sigma(\tau)$. Not rigorously, but because we could construct each $(a_n, b_n]$ by taking $(b_n, \infty) \in \tau \Rightarrow (-\infty, b_n] \in \sigma(\tau), (a_n, \infty) \: \cap \: (-\infty, b_n] = (a_n, b_n]$, and so also all unions of those terms. (If this is correct)
But I don't see how to go the other way around. How do we show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A})$? How do I show that every open set is $\in \sigma(\mathcal{A})$?
